# Cancellable NSOperation with NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, httprequest, nsoperation

I'm writing an `NSOperation` to make a web service request via a `NSURLConnection`. I would like to make the `NSOperation` able to be cancelled, so that a long-running HTTP request can be interrupted if necessary. If I make the HTTP request synchronously, it will block the thread and I can't check `isCancelled` to terminate early. Making the HTTP request asynchronously from the `NSOperation` doesn't make sense to me (where would the delegate methods be?). What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) for this type of problem.  `ASIHTTPRequest` objects are `NSOperation` subclasses, and support cancelling, custom timeout periods, and blocks.

Comment: Is there a way to do stick with just NSOperationQueue and NSURLConnection

Comment: Yes, but it is not trivial, and I'm assuming you'd rather spend time solving the problems that are unique to your app rather than common networking problems that have been tackled already. I'd suggest Mattt's excellent [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) library instead of concocting your own solution.